# experimentalDecorators and emitDecoratorMetadata

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a confusion with experimentalDecorators and emitDecoratorMetadata in tsConfig file.

We have to set experimentalDecorators to true, which let us use the experimental feature that is decorators in the application. Experimental means they may get removed in the future. Isn't it risky to use decorators in that case?

Also I want to understand the meaning of emitDecoratorMetadata.

Comment: experimental because the ECMAScript proposal was not finalized.
I believe it is now finalize and one issue on TS github is to making it official.